# How to merge two list of dicts if value of key is the same?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given two list of dicts, how can they be merged based on the value of a specific key `id`?

```
#List of dicts1
players = [ {'age': '19 years 275 days',
  'birth': '24 July 2000',
  'birth_exact': 964396800000.0,
  'country': 'Ecuador',
  'first': 'Leonardo',
  'id': 74562.0,
  'isoCode': 'EC',
  'last': 'Campana',
  'loan': False,
  'name': 'Leonardo Campana',
  'nationalTeam': 'Ecuador',
  'playerId': 179304.0,
  'position': 'F',
  'positionInfo': 'Centre Striker',
  'season': 2019,
  'shirtNum': None},
 {'age': '24 years 186 days',
  'birth': '21 October 1995',
  'birth_exact': 814233600000.0,
  'country': 'Portugal',
  'first': 'Daniel',
  'id': 11362.0,
  'isoCode': 'PT',
  'last': 'Castelo Podence',
  'loan': False,
  'name': 'Daniel Podence',
  'nationalTeam': 'Portugal',
  'playerId': 180050.0,
  'position': 'M',
  'positionInfo': 'Left/Right Winger',
  'season': 2019,
  'shirtNum': 10.0}]

#List of dicts2
squad = [ {'id': 11362.0,
  'team': 'Arsenal',
  'team_id':1,
  'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'},
 {'id': 74562.0,
  'team': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  'team_id': 38,
  'team_shortName': 'Wolves'}]
```

I want to merge the info in `squad` to `players`.

I have tried the following:

```
p_sort = sorted(players, key=lambda k: k['id']) 
s_sort = sorted(squad, key=lambda k: k['id']) 
l3 = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(p_sort, s_sort, fillvalue={})]
return l3
```

But a small problem is that the two list of dicts is of different length so this solution does not work as intended. How can this be solved?

Expected output:

```
l3 = [ {'age': '19 years 275 days',
  'birth': '24 July 2000',
  'birth_exact': 964396800000.0,
  'country': 'Ecuador',
  'first': 'Leonardo',
  'id': 74562.0,
  'isoCode': 'EC',
  'last': 'Campana',
  'loan': False,
  'name': 'Leonardo Campana',
  'nationalTeam': 'Ecuador',
  'playerId': 179304.0,
  'position': 'F',
  'positionInfo': 'Centre Striker',
  'season': 2019,
  'shirtNum': None,
  'team': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  'team_id': 38,
  'team_shortName': 'Wolves'}},

 {'age': '24 years 186 days',
  'birth': '21 October 1995',
  'birth_exact': 814233600000.0,
  'country': 'Portugal',
  'first': 'Daniel',
  'id': 11362.0,
  'isoCode': 'PT',
  'last': 'Castelo Podence',
  'loan': False,
  'name': 'Daniel Podence',
  'nationalTeam': 'Portugal',
  'playerId': 180050.0,
  'position': 'M',
  'positionInfo': 'Left/Right Winger',
  'season': 2019,
  'shirtNum': 10.0},
  'team': 'Arsenal',
  'team_id': 1,
  'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'}]
```

Comment: The only issue I can find with your code is that you define `squad = ...`, but when sorting you call to `squads`

Comment: @Alexander That was a spelling misstake, sorry!

Comment: So I've put your code into console and it worked for me well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some of your data to reduce output - you can use 2 dictionaries to get fast acces to what id is in what list (squads vs players).

You loop once over player list and update them if they got a squad with same key - you can also use the dicts to assert wether all sqads got player infos:

```
players = [ {'age': '19 years 275 days',
  'birth': '24 July 2000', 
  'id': 74562.0  },
 {'age': '24 years 186 days',
  'birth': '21 October 1995',
  'birth_exact': 814233600000.0,
  'id': 11362.0,}, 
  {'age': '24 years 186 days',
  'birth': '21 October 1995',
  'birth_exact': 814233600000.0,
  'id':42,}]

# fixed name
squads = [ {'id': 11362.0,
  'team': 'Arsenal',
  'team_id':1,
  'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'},
 {'id': 74562.0,
  'team': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  'team_id': 38,
  'team_shortName': 'Wolves'},
  {'id': -3,
  'team': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  'team_id': 38,
  'team_shortName': 'Wolves'}]

p_sort = sorted(players, key=lambda k: k['id']) 
s_sort = sorted(squads, key=lambda k: k['id']) 

keyed_players = {a["id"]:a for a in p_sort} # easier access for IN - check
keyed_squads = {a["id"]:a for a in s_sort}  # easier access for IN - check

# iterate players and modify them if squad info given, else printout info
for player in p_sort:
    if player["id"] in keyed_squads:
        player.update(keyed_squads[player["id"]])
    else:
        print("player", player["id"], "has no squad info")

print(p_sort)

# get squads without players
for s in keyed_squads:
    if s not in keyed_players:
        print("squad", s, "has no player info")
```

Output:

```
player 42 has no squad info

[{'age': '24 years 186 days', 'birth': '21 October 1995', 
  'birth_exact': 814233600000.0, 'id': 42}, 
 {'age': '24 years 186 days', 'birth': '21 October 1995', 
  'birth_exact': 814233600000.0, 'id': 11362.0, 
  'team': 'Arsenal', 'team_id': 1, 'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'}, 
 {'age': '19 years 275 days', 'birth': '24 July 2000', 'id': 74562.0, 
  'team': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', 'team_id': 38, 'team_shortName': 'Wolves'}]

squad -3 has no player info
```

The code for sure holds more lines then yours - but it is much clearer what does what - wich might be a bonus if you look at it in 4 weeks.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, This is precisely what I'm looking for, I tested it against the real data and it pinpointed the discrepancies between the two datasets (should have same length). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
res = [{**x, **y}  for y in players for x in squad if x['id'] == y['id']]
d = [dict(sorted(d.items())) for d in res]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'age': '19 years 275 days', 'birth': '24 July 2000', 'birth_exact': 964396800000.0, 'country': 'Ecuador', 'first': 'Leonardo', 'id': 74562.0, 'isoCode': 'EC', 'last': 'Campana', 'loan': False, 'name': 'Leonardo Campana', 'nationalTeam': 'Ecuador', 'playerId': 179304.0, 'position': 'F', 'positionInfo': 'Centre Striker', 'season': 2019, 'shirtNum': None, 'team': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', 'team_id': 38, 'team_shortName': 'Wolves'}, {'age': '24 years 186 days', 'birth': '21 October 1995', 'birth_exact': 814233600000.0, 'country': 'Portugal', 'first': 'Daniel', 'id': 11362.0, 'isoCode': 'PT', 'last': 'Castelo Podence', 'loan': False, 'name': 'Daniel Podence', 'nationalTeam': 'Portugal', 'playerId': 180050.0, 'position': 'M', 'positionInfo': 'Left/Right Winger', 'season': 2019, 'shirtNum': 10.0, 'team': 'Arsenal', 'team_id': 1, 'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'}]
```

Comment: Very nice solution it worked seamlessly, I will have to evaluate it on the real data, since there are discrepancies. At first glans I't seems that it disregards id's that can't be matched between the sets so that they are not included in the output. A length test of each dict confirms that all dicts are successful. Thank you!